# Please reopen this Juju question

Tags: discussion

["did not find expected hexadecimal number" when bootstraping Juju on Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368783/did-not-find-expected-hexadecimal-number-when-bootstraping-juju-on-windows)

I probably have an answer for this one once the OP responds, don't know why it was closed.

Comment: I would guess because it says Windows in it and shows a big path with back-slashes and starting in a `C:\`. That's autoclose for most people... They can't see past that to see it's about Juju and is therefore a protected class.

Comment: Ps, I've reopened it.

Comment: @Oli *<facepalm>* They shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remember commenting in another question, that was being closed, like this:

> Juju is free to use. The Juju server runs on any system with Ubuntu Server installed from your laptop to private cloud to any certified public clouds. The client current runs on any Ubuntu system, **Mac OS X or Windows**.

With Juju and Ubuntu One you must remember that they are on-topic, even if they are on Windows.